# Generating union string Type

Tags: typescript

I'm validating a string:

```
type Option = 'm' | 'm2' | 'm3' | 'ft' | 'ft2' | 'ft3'

const optionGood: Option = 'm'
const optionError: Option = 'other text' // Type '"other text"' is not assignable to type 'Option'.ts(2322)
```

This is really bothersome, because in a real solution, number of options is a three digit number. I'd love to create something like this:

```
type Unit = 'm' | 'ft'
type Suffix = '' | '2' | '3'

// this line is fictional and doesn't work, but shows what I'm trying to accomplish
type Option = `${Unit}${Suffix}`
```

I tried using `stringEnum` to generate options:

```
/** Utility function to create a K:V from a list of strings */
export function stringEnum<T extends string>(array: Array<T>): { [K in T]: K } {
  return array.reduce((res, key) => {
    res[key] = key
    return res
  }, Object.create(null))
}

const Options = stringEnum(['m', 'm2'])
// 'm' | 'm2'
type Options = keyof typeof Options
```

This works with static array only. If you try to provide a variable with an array to the `stringEnum`, Options type becomes simple `string` or `any` type:

```
const options = ['m', 'm2']
const Options = stringEnum(options)
// string
type Options = keyof typeof Options
```

I have an array of all options that I want to include into `Options` type, but I'm not sure how to approach this. So my question is, ***how do I generate a union string type from an array?***

I'm even starting to consider `Node` task that generates `Options.ts` file (double compilation?).

Comment: There is no support in the type system to do string manipulations. If you really want to compile time validate such a type then generating a ts file is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Your "double compliation" idea may be the only way to automate this right now.

---

There is a suggestion in GitHub to support [regular-expression-validated `string` types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6579), but this has not made it into the language as of TS3.5 and doesn't seem to be on the immediate roadmap.  If it were, you might be able to do something like

```
// ⚠ the next line is just proposed syntax and does not currently work in TS ⚠
type Option = /^(m|ft)[23]?$/
```

You may want to go over to that issue and give it a  or describe your use case if you think it's more compelling than what's already in there... but I wouldn't hold my breath waiting for this.

---

Another relevant issue in GitHub is a suggestion to support [augmenting keys in mapped types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12754).  This feature is also not part of the language as of TS3.5 and doesn't look like it's being actively worked on.   If it were present, you might be able to do something like

```
type Unit = 'm' | 'ft'
type Suffix = '' | '2' | '3'
// ⚠ the next line is just proposed syntax and does not currently work in TS ⚠  
type Option = { [S in Suffix]: keyof { [U in Unit] + S: any } }[Suffix];
```

Again, you may want to give the issue a  or describe your use case (although I'd think general string concatenation might be off-label for this)... and again, I wouldn't expect much here any time soon.

---

Oh well.  Hope that helps somewhat.  Good luck!